# SF novel featuring a member of a disbanded rock/punk group

Tags: story-identification, books

I can't specify the SFnal aspects of the book, because I only remember the band parts, but it definitely was.  Read sometime after the nineties but before around 2015.

Set in USA or UK in a near "present" time, with a similar feel to "Pattern Recognition" by William Gibson.
Main character was a youngish female (<30?), ex-member of a rock/indie/punk band, now disbanded, although in their day they were the ultimate in cool - skinny, mop haircuts, black T-shirts, sort of style.
Main character is now slightly embarrassed when she is recognised.
The band members are still on good terms, but have little contact.

Can't remember anymore. Hope it's not closed for lack of SF content. As I said, I remember it having a Gibson vibe.

Comment: Hm... it really does help if you can define some science fiction aspect to it. So, none of the band members had cybernetics? Direct interface to the web? Hyperadvanced holograms? Space travel is part of the setting?

Comment: Does the name "Hollis Henry" sound familiar?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about Science Fiction or Fantasy, as defined in the [FAQ] and Help Centre

Comment: @Valorum If it's by Gibson it's SF, though increasingly in the same way as Guy Gavriel Kay's work is fantasy.

Comment: @DavidW - OP didn't say it's by Gibson, they said it has a Gibson kinda feel. As things stand I can't see anything on-topic in this question other than OPs vague but confident assertion that it's 'definitely SFNal'

Comment: @Valorum True, but on the other hand, OP says it's feels like Gibson, and it sounds like _Spook Country_ so it might be on-topic. :)

Comment: If the questioner is sure that that it was SF (even if they don't remember any science fiction aspects), it's on topic.

Comment: @Buzz - Ugh. It's been six years since we last voted on that. I think we need to look at it again; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12176/20774

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you're looking for the sequel to *Pattern Recognition*, *[Spook Country](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spook_Country)* which features a musician turned reporter.

**Main character was a youngish female (<30?), ex-member of a rock/indie/punk band**

> The first strand of the novel follows Hollis Henry, a former member of
> the early 1990s cult band The Curfew and a freelance journalist

This [review](https://www.tor.com/2009/07/14/mediating-the-immediate-william-gibsons-spook-country/) adds:

> Its only major character who has wholly real, immediate, and
> unmediated experiences is Hollis—but she’s the former singer of The
> Curfew, a Pixies-esque once-cult now-famous rock band; and so
> everyone’s experience of her is filtered through her fame, and the
> iconic Anton Corbijn photo of her in a tweed miniskirt

SF elements include use of "[locative art](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locative_media)" which allows multimedia displays to show up on someone's devices based on their location in the world (now an existing phenomenon, but somewhat futuristic when the book came out).

Comment: You could improve this answer by including details that actually match the question. :-P